# xmllint extract value without xpath

Tags: xml-parsing, xmllint

I need to verify xml textvalue of an  element in my xml as show below, so far I got the value of all the dmdindex:field but I just need the last one **drep.rightsFacet** result output. Keep in mind that xmllint version I have does not have xpath so I have to resort to xmllint --shell. Any help is appreciated.

here's the xml file snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dmdindex:dmdindex xmlns:dmdindex="http://www.example.com/example/dmdindex/"
                   xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com"
                   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <dmdindex:record>
      <dmdindex:field name="drep.yearStart">1881</dmdindex:field>
      <dmdindex:field name="drep.pubConcat">[Detroit : Parke, Davis &amp; Co., 1881?]</dmdindex:field>
      <dmdindex:field name="drep.rights">blahblahblah</dmdindex:field>
      <dmdindex:field name="drep.rightsLink">https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/mark/1.0/</dmdindex:field>
      <dmdindex:field name="drep.rightsFacet">Public domain</dmdindex:field>
   </dmdindex:record>
</dmdindex:dmdindex>
```

here's the command I used

```
echo "cat //*[local-name()='dmdindex']/*[local-name()='record']/*[local-name()='field']" | xmllint --shell example.xml | sed '/^\/ >/d' | sed 's/<[^>]*.//g'
```

which returned

```
 -------
Philadelphia : Sunshine Press, [1897]
 -------
blahblahblah
 -------
https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/mark/1.0/
 -------
Public domain
```

I only need to grab the value of "Public domain" and ignore the rest. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a predicate to your xpath to test the value of the `name` attribute...

```
echo "cat //*[local-name()='dmdindex']/*[local-name()='record']/*[local-name()='field'][@name='drep.rightsFacet']/text()" | xmllint --shell example.xml | sed '/^\/ >/d'
```